# How to set command output as env. variable in windows cmd?

Tags: windows, terraform, azure-cli

I have saved azure storage key in key vault and i want to retrieve the key using Azure cli and set it as env. variable in window cmd before i run terraform script.

Below listed command doesn't work, can anyone tell me what needs to be changed ?

```
set ARM_ACCESS_KEY=$(az keyvault secret show --name terraform-backend-key --vault-name myKeyVault)
```

Error on initializing

[image]

Main.tf

```
variable "count" {}
variable "prefix" {
default="RG"
 }
terraform {
backend "azurerm" {
container_name       = "new"
storage_account_name  = "mfarg"
key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
}}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
count ="${var.count}"
name     = "${var.prefix}-${count.index}"
location = "West US 2"
}
```

Command prompt output

[image]

Comment: If you don't get enough answers here, you might also wish to ask a similar question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: you are assigning a multi-line JSON document to a variable which probably fails. use "--query path --output tsv" to get just the property you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the environment variable in Windows, I suggest you use the PowerShell command to achieve it. In PowerShell, you can just do it like this:

```
$env:ACCESS_KEY=$(az keyvault secret show -n terraform-backend-key --vault-name myKeyVault --query value -o tsv)
```

Also, in your CLI command, you could not show the secret directly, it outputs the whole secret not just the access key as you want. See the difference between the two commands.

[image]

Comment: I tried setting env. variable as suggested by you, but after setting it am getting an error on terraform init (Using terraform remote state azure storage) to store state file on azure,  is the error related to azureRM module ? because i am working on new AZ module

Comment: @user2549572 Store the state in the Azure storage, you should export the environment variable `ARM_ACCESS_KEY`, not `ACCESS_KEY`. I just show you how to set the environment variable through PowerShell.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. it worked after changing the name.  Can you also tel me how to set env. variable using command prompt ?

Comment: @user2549572 You can use the command that you provide `set var=''`. But it seems you can set the variable with the output of the CLI command directly.

Comment: I tried doing that but it takes the whole command as a value instead of its output, screenshot attached

Comment: @user2549572 As I said, it seems you cannot set the output of the command as a variable directly. I also do not find the way.

Comment: Windows cmd != powershell

Answer (score 3):

A late answer, but perhaps useful to those who still have the same problem.
This method will work in windows Command prompt, cmd.

```
For /f %%i in ('az keyvault secret show --vault-name "Your-KeyVault-Name" --name "Your-Secret-Name" --query "value"') do set "password=%%i"
```

Now if you just run "echo %password%" you will see your secret value.
Remember that az command has to be between ' ', like 'az keyvault secret etc'.

Comment: works like a charm in the correct cmd terminal! %%i changes to %i on the regular command prompt. It is %%i in a batch .bat or .cmd script